# Higher or Lower game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a simple python game where you have to guess whether the next number will be higher or lower. The number range that the computer can pick is 1, 21.

The user inputs higher or lower (H or L) and the computer randomly generates a second number which it then checks against the first to determine whether the user guessed correctly.

The issue I am coming up against is that once the computer generates the second number, I want the loop to then continue with that as the number that the user has to guess against.

For example:

computer number - 11
user inputs higher
second number - 15

user is correct. They then have to guess whether the next number will be higher or lower than 15.

I am unable to get the second number to be the number the user guesses against and instead the loop is starting again with the number always at 11 which is the starting point I set.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Code:

```
streak = 0
print(artwork.title)
print("Welcome to High or Low!\nDo you think the next number will be higher or lower?")
print("\nThe game always starts with the number 11, get a streak of 5 to win!")
end_of_game = False


while not end_of_game:
first_number = 11
second_number = random.randint(1, 21)

player_input = input("\nHigher or Lower? Type H or L\n").lower()

if player_input == "h" and second_number > first_number:
    streak += 1
    print(f"{second_number} Correct!")
    first_number = second_number
    print(f"Current Streak is: {streak}")
    print(f"\n\nThe current number is: {first_number}")
    if streak == 5:
        print("Congratulations YOU WIN!")
        end_of_game = True
elif player_input == "l" and second_number > first_number:
    print(f"{second_number}, Unlucky")
    print("\nTry again, the number is 11")
    streak = 0
elif player_input == "h" and second_number < first_number:
    print(f"{second_number}, Unlucky")
    print("\nTry again, the number is 11")
    streak = 0
elif player_input == "l" and second_number < first_number:
    streak += 1
    print(f"{second_number} Correct!")
    first_number = second_number
    print(f"Current Streak is: {streak}")
    print(f"\n\nThe current number is: {first_number}")
    if streak == 5:
        print("Congratulations YOU WIN!")
        end_of_game = True
```

I've only been doing this for a week so my code looks like alphabet soup.. Apologies!

Comment: you may really like [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), The Python Debugger .. invoke as a module and you can set breakpoints and inspect your code live `python -m pdb myscript.py` for debugging small programs like this

Comment: If you calculated a variable `is_correct_guess` based on a test for either of the correct guess conditions can you see how that might make the rest of your code simpler?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I'm still thinking about the long way to do stuff and not thinking how things can be simplified. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're resetting `first_number` to `11` at the top of the loop:

```
while not end_of_game:
    first_number = 11
    ...
```

So even though you set `first_number = second_number` in the loop when the player wins, it's just getting reset to `11` on the next iteration.

To fix it, just move the initialization out of the loop, so it only executes once, before entering the loop:

```
first_number = 11
while not end_of_game:
    ...
```